# DateTime in Calender Weeks

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a Dataframe and the index has the calender week + year in the following format:
01.2015
02.2015 and so on

How to I convert it to a dateime? I want to do a seasonal decomposition, so my index needs to be a datetime.

Answer (score 0):

To convert your date string to *datetime* run:

```
df['Dat2'] = pd.to_datetime('1.' + df.Dat, format='%w.%W.%Y')
```

In the above format string:

- *%w* is the weekday as a decimal number (Sunday = 0, Satunday = 6).
- *%W* is the week number.
- *%Y* is the year number.

The weekday number is constant (*1*) and week / year number come from the source data.

For the test I used the followig DataFrame (*Dat* column as **string**):

```
       Dat
0  01.2015
1  02.2015
2  01.2019
3  02.2019
```

The result of my code is:

```
       Dat       Dat2
0  01.2015 2015-01-05
1  02.2015 2015-01-12
2  01.2019 2019-01-07
3  02.2019 2019-01-14
```